# cannot find symbol: parseInt

Tags: java, parseint

I have allready compiled a few tiny programms in java and everything was fine. But my new code has any problem.

```
class myclass
{
 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  int x, y;
  String s ="sssss";
  x=args.length;
  s= args[0].substring(1,2);
  System.out.println("Num of args: "+x);
  System.out.println("List of args:");
  y = parseInt(s,5);
  }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
 e:\java\4>javac myclass.java 
  myclass.java:11: error: cannot find symbol   
   y = parseInt(s,5);
       ^   symbol:   method parseInt(String,int)   location: class myclass 1 error

 e:\java\4>
```

The strange thing is that the compiler jumps over the method substring (as there is no problem) but the method parseInt seems to have any problem.
y = parseInt(s); OR: y = parseInt("Hello"); --> Also the same compiler message.

Or does the method not exist? [docs.oracle-->Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) says it exists :)

It makes my really crazy **as i don't know how to search for the error**. I have checked the internet allready, i checked the classpath and the path...

So it would be great if any expert could help me. :)

Comment: Java's Integer.parseInt has an optional radix parameter. But make sure you want a radix of 5. If you are trying to parse "regular" number inputs, you can just ommit the radix completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**parseInt**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) is a **static** method in **Integer** class. you need to call it like this:

```
  y = Integer.parseInt(s,5);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i think alone i didn't get it by the end of this year.

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying to access a static method of the `Integer` class

You must do:

```
y = Integer.parseInt(s,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` is static method of Integer class. To invoke it you have to do one of few things:

1. invoke it on Integer class

   ```
    y = Integer.parseInt(s, 5)
   ```
2. invoke it on *variable* of Integer type (but this way is discouraged since such code still will be compiled into `Integer.parseInt` but will *look* like `parseInt` is instance method - so non-static which is not true and may cause confusion)

   ```
    Integer i = null;//yes reference can be even null in this case
    y = i.parseInt(s, 5);
   ```
3. import that static method using *static import* via `import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;`. This way you can use that method directly:

   ```
    y = parseInt(s,5);
   ```